# Why don't the "hidden" and "loop" attribute do anything?

Tags: html, microsoft-edge, background-music

Ok, i pretty much just finished my tetris game. So now i wanted to implement the music  - which i did like this: `<embed src="Tetris.mp3" autostart="true" loop=infinite hidden="true">`

Now, the autostart works, but the music doesn't loop after it ends, and also the music player isn't hidden.
I'm using Microsoft Edge, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this

```
<audio controls autoplay loop hidden>
  <source src="Tetris.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```